# how can i pass an url parameter between two xhtml pages?

Tags: jsf, viewparams

i am trying to pass a parameter between two pages

in the bean i have this string with getters and setters 
outcome is the function to run with the button

```
@Named("MeubleBean")
@ManagedBean 
@SessionScoped 
@RequestScoped
public class MeubleBean implements Serializable {
 private String param1;

 public String outcome() {

FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
Map<String, String> params = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
param1 = params.get("param1Name");


return "meubles3.jsf?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
}
}
```

the code of the command button in the page meubles.xhtml :

```
         <f:param id="param1" name="param1Name" value="param1Value"/>
            </h:commandButton>
```

and finally the output in meubles3.xhtml :

```
<h:form><h:outputText value="#{meubleBean.param1}"></h:outputText>
</h:form>
```

i am trying the "param1value" as test value .
the output is always empty, i tried several ways none of em worked.
any solution please ???

Comment: i have getters and setter and other code so i did not copy it, and i generated it automatically

Comment: You are mixing annotations. If you use the CDI annotation `@Named` you should not use `ManagedBean`. Use only one scope, request or session.

Comment: You are using `value="#{meubleBean.param1}"`, do you have a getter `getParam1()`?

Comment: Please always use good indentation in the code you post

Comment: @Holger yes i do have getters and setters and i generated it automatically, i actually almost copied and pasted this code from a tutorial. and i used the named because without it it wasn't detecting the bean . by the way, i can read variables the get is working but i can't set em.